# Aircraft rotations in 3d game

Tags: 3d, rotation, quaternion

It seems like rotating plane in 3d game on certain axis is not solution because they change based on current rotation. Also there is gimbal lock problem, so i guess i should use quaternions.
Is there any good examples/tutorials how to find delta angles for rotations and use quaternions in similar cases? Language or engine does not matter.

Comment: The key thing you need to learn about is `Quaternions`. You can use a quaternion to rotate an object in 3D space without the gimbal lock issue.

Comment: This is not the place to ask for links to existing examples or tutorials. [Typing "quaternion tutorial" into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=quaternion+tutorial&ia=web) is the way to get that. This site is for things that you cannot find adequately explained in existing resources. If you can **edit your question** to demonstrate a specific rotation operation you need help implementing with quaternions, then folks here can post answers explaining how to do that operation.